# Find hidden options with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, select

I'm trying to basically 'select' options that are visible, and hide certain options with css.

My two issues are that a: Css display none on options doesn't actually hide the options. So I'm assuming that this is why jquery can't determine if it's visible or not?

**HTML:**

```
<select form="id" name="horse_discipline" id="horse_discipline" class="">
    <option value="null">Please Choose</option>
    <option value="mature_working_or_spelling">Mature – Working or Spelling</option>
    <option value="pregnant_1_8_months">Pregnant 1-8 Months</option>
    <option value="pregnant_9_-11_months">Pregnant 9-11 Months</option>
    <option value="lactating">Lactating</option>
    <option value="weanling">Weanling</option>
    <option value="yearling">Yearling</option>
    <option value="2_year_old_working_or_spelling">2 Year Old - Working or Spelling</option>
    <option value="breeding_stallion">Breeding Stallion</option>
    <option value="aged">Aged</option>
</select>
```

If I inspect my select element, and the option inside, using the following css rule, it looks like the css is being applied, but the display of the option is ignored.

`option[value="weanling"] {display:none;}`

My question is, is it possible to select options that are visible, or not visible with jquery and a combination of css.

```
$('select#horse_discipline option').each(function(){
     var visible = $(this).is(':visible');
     // Do something with visible var
})
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/vgLhU/1/

Comment: Can you include your HTML?

Comment: Your code to check when the options are visible is running on DOM ready, at which time none of the options are visible because the select isn't open. If you mean something different please show us some code showing the exact issue.

Comment: Even when I do open the select menu, the css isn't applied to the option it's selecting, it's still visible @winterblood

Comment: I can't see the option in Chrome 36 or Firefox 31.

Comment: Chrome < 36 has this issue, firefox doesn't have the issue at all

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap you options with a `span` which is not HTML conform. This should work cross Browser. Maybe it is a better idea to populate options on demand. I often use JavaScript template engines like Handlebars.JS.

Comment: Wrapping `options` in `spans` would create invalid HTML, and is more likely to cause cross-browser issues.

Comment: I mentioned this. I think it is possible to use <option hidden>Hidden</option> whis is on the other hand not CSS, but jQuery selector should find this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the `disabled` attribute is the way to go here, I'll have to use a bit of javascript to add the attribute but it seems like it's more supported.

```
<select form="id" name="horse_discipline" id="horse_discipline" class="">
    <option value="null">Please Choose</option>
    <option value="mature_working_or_spelling">Mature – Working or Spelling</option>
    <option value="pregnant_1_8_months">Pregnant 1-8 Months</option>
    <option value="pregnant_9_-11_months" disabled>Pregnant 9-11 Months</option>
    <option value="lactating">Lactating</option>
    <option value="weanling">Weanling</option>
    <option value="yearling">Yearling</option>
    <option value="2_year_old_working_or_spelling" disabled="disabled">2 Year Old - Working or Spelling</option>
    <option value="breeding_stallion">Breeding Stallion</option>
    <option value="aged">Aged</option>
</select>
```

Javscript:

```
$('select#horse_discipline option').each(function(){
     var disabled = $(this).is(':disabled');
     if (!disabled) {
          // Do something with the disabled option
     }
})
```

DEMO:: http://jsfiddle.net/vgLhU/2/